# Docker hub/registry automated build from github build details log

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am using the automated build feature on `hub.docker`.

This works very well, when I push a change to a Github repo this triggers the image to be built on hub.docker. Since this image is large (it takes around 35mins to build) I am often left wondering how things are going on inside.

On the `Build Details` tab of the automated build I can see when the latest image was created, last updated and it's status. This looks like this:

[image: Build Details screenshot]

When the build finishes, I can click on the build and see the `logs`. This is a full break down and very useful for debugging. However, this often means waiting around for the finish of the build (35mins).

Previously I had experimented with Quay and they had some really nice logging features that gave me an idea of what was happening internally.

Is there a Docker feature that I am missing?

I have added a `slack` webhook but there are no notifications during the build process.